# Rename menu item in Android

Tags: android

I would like to rename menu on click of an item. I tried the following but it didn't change.

I tried **item.setTitle("LandScape");** or              **item.setTitle("Portrait");**

Declare the menu:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Do something on click on the menu item:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    boolean result = true;

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {

    case R.id.oscillation_mode:
    {
        if(getScreenOrientation() == 1)
        {
            Log.e("Orientation","ABC"+getScreenOrientation());

            item.setTitle("LandScape");
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
        else 
        {

            item.setTitle("Portrait");
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        break;
    }
```

The text is the same. The default it is Portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call `setRequestedOrientation()` your `Activity` is destroyed and recreated, so any changes you make to in memory objects will be dropped. You should make these changes when the menu is shown instead

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem oscillation = menu.findItem(R.id.oscillation_mode);
    if (getScreenOrientation() == 1){
        item.setTitle("LandScape");
    }else{
        item.setTitle("Portrait");
    }

    return true;
}
```